# what are the alternatives besides openGLUT and x-windows for creating windows in linux environment?

Tags: linux, x11

while learning computer graphics in linux environment, I have choice to use openGLUT or X-windows for creating windows.

What are the other choices (libraries) available to create windows in linux environment besides openGLUT and x-windows?

Comment: OpenGLUT Is for using OpenGL (3D graphics)..  x-windows is more properly written XWindow - nobody uses it directly.  If you want to do 3D OpenGLUT is fine.  If you want a regular GUI try KDE or Gnome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Qt](http://qt.digia.com/) or [Gtk](http://gtk.org/) or perhaps [libsdl](http://www.libsdl.org/), [fox-toolkit](http://www.fox-toolkit.org/), [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/index.php) (or some other [widget toolkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit) ....)

Most of them are above [X11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11) which you don't want to use directly. BTW, X11 might become phased out and be eventually replaced with [wayland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_%28display_server_protocol%29), [mir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMir) or something else (but GTK and Qt are compatible with that evolution).

Alternatively, consider providing a Web HTML5 interface (so use some HTTP server library like [wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt), [libonion](http://coralbits.com/libonion/) etc....)